# Rails 4 update nested models using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get a Rails 4 based api (not using views/forms) to accept a json object graph and update all of the associated models. I wasn't having any luck on the main project so I created a basic project to try to get it to work and I cannot get Rails to allow the elements in the json data for the nested models to be "permitted" parameters.

I have three models: Top, Middle and Bottom. Top has many Middles and Middle has many Bottoms. Everyting is setup in the database and I have a TopsController that I'm using to receive the PUT:

**app/controllers/api/tops_controller.rb:**

```
class Api::TopsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def show
    all = Top.all
    render json: { result: "success", tops: all }
  end

  def update
    top = Top.find(params[:top][:id])
    top.update(top_params)
    render json: { result: "updated", top: top }
  end


  private

  def top_params
    params.require(:top).permit(:name, :middles_attributes => [:id, :name])
  end

end
```

**app/models/top.rb:**

```
class Top < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :middles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :middles, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  def as_json(options = {})
    attrs = self.attributes
    attrs['middles'] = self.middles
    attrs
  end

end
```

**app/models/middle.rb:**

```
class Middle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :top
  has_many :bottoms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bottoms, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  def as_json(options = {})
    attrs = self.attributes
    attrs['bottoms'] = self.bottoms
    attrs
  end
end
```

**app/models/bottom.rb:**

```
class Bottom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :middle
end
```

This is the update.json file I'm cURLing to the server:

```
{
    "top":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"NewTopName",
        "middles":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"UpdatedMiddleName",
                "top_id":1,
                "bottoms":[
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"UpdatedBottomName",
                        "middle_id":1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I cURL it using:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @update.json  http://localhost:3000/top/edit
```

The Top.name property is updated every time, no problem, but the Middle and Bottom data is ignored. Looking at the server output I see this:

```
Started PUT "/top/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-09 17:09:24 -0700
Processing by Api::TopsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"top"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"NewTopName", "middles"=>[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"UpdatedMiddleName", "top_id"=>1, "bottoms"=>[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"UpdatedBottomName", "middle_id"=>1}]}]}}
  Top Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tops".* FROM "tops"  WHERE "tops"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: id, middles
...
```

The `Unpermitted parameters: id, middles` part seems to be telling me that it can't(won't) process those middles parameters in the update, even though I've permitted them in the TopsController::top_params method using `:middles_attributes => [:id, :name]` (and a few other ways, including `... :middles => []`).

I'm clearly missing something here, but I cannot for the life of me see what it is. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try to permit bottoms params also like :middles_attributes => [:id, :name, :top_id, :bottoms_attributes => [:id, :name, middle_id]]

Comment: In update.json, `middles_attributes` needs to replace the key `middles` and same for `bottoms`, `bottoms_attributes`.

Comment: @rossta - That worked! Is that just a convention that follows from when people usually use a generated form for this purpose? Either way I love you as much as one random internet user can love another random internet user :-) If you form your comment into an answer I'll mark it accepted. anusha - thanks for the format for inserting the "bottoms" into the permits line. That also worked like a charm!

Comment: @randall It is indeed a naming convention, but it has a specific purpose in that Rails will attempt to build a dependent object (such as middle or bottom) from the parameter map by looking for a key called *_attributes (where * is the name of your dependent model). Its caused by using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.